# A question about the the usage of verb+ing in a sentence

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

> City people’s sufferings will worsen further in the upcoming days as indiscriminate road digging and channel grabbing continue **giving** rise to fears of severe waterlogging in the coming monsoon.

- What is the parts of speech of 'giving' here? Is it adjective? And is it present perfect form?
- Can I make it like this?

> City people’s sufferings will worsen further in the upcoming days as indiscriminate road digging and channel grabbing continue.

- Is a comma is needed here?

> City people’s sufferings will worsen further in the upcoming days as indiscriminate road digging and channel grabbing **continue,** giving rise to fears of severe waterlogging in the coming monsoon.

- Does this sentence below represent the same form of structure of verb+ing?

> It caused her great pain leaving the only option to abandon her duty.

Comment: The third one with a comma after 'continue' seems OK. The second example is OK too, but seems to stop a little abruptly.

Comment: There's an ambiguity: does "continue giving rise" mean that they have given rise to something for a long period, or is the fact that something was continuing just now giving rise to something. In the latter case, a comma is better, in the former "continue to give rise" might be better than "continue giving".